# how to send message to parent process

Tags: node.js

Can I send message to parent process?

master

```
var child =child_process.fork();

child.send({msg:msg})
```

child process

```
process.on('message', function(){

});

// how to send message to parent??
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short use: `process.send()`

Longer example, I wrote awhile ago named `forktest.js`:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

if (!process.send) {
  var p = cp.fork(__dirname + '/forktest');
  p.send({
    count: 10
  });
  p.on('message', function(data) {
    process.exit(0);
  });
} else {
  process.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    data.count--;
    if (data.count === 0) {
      process.send({});
      process.exit(0);
    }
    var p = cp.fork(__dirname + '/forktest');
    p.send(data);
    p.on('message', function(data) {
      process.send(data);
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `if (process.argv[2]) ` any other better way to identify master/child

Comment: I think it might be clearer to use: `!process.send` which is true if this process is not a child of another.

Comment: @DanD. not entirely true, since IPC may not be created, and there will not be a send method.

Comment: @senz Well, it is possible to spawn a child process that just happens to be node that isn't connected to its parent via `child_process.exec` but `child_process.fork` always results in a node process connected its parent.