# How to execute user submitted javascript code in sandbox environment in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So what I am trying to do is as take a javascript code as input from user and return him the result. Right now I am executing the code submitted by user just using eval (with some safety checks). But I understand this is highly unreliable. So what I want to achieve is run this in sandbox environment safely and return the result to user.
E.g

Input:

```
var a =[1,2,3];
a.map(n => n*2);
```

Output:

```
[2,4,6]
```

I tried using vm in node but I don't really understand how to get the final result from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using vm in node but I don't really understand how to get the final result from it.

Many [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/vm.html) functions, like [`vm.runInNewContext()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options), will return the result of the last statement in the string, similar to `eval()`.

```
var vm = require('vm');
var script = 'var a = [1, 2, 3]; a.map(n => n * 2);';

var sandbox = {};
var result = vm.runInNewContext(script, sandbox);

console.log(sandbox); // { a: [1, 2, 3] }
console.log(result);  // [2, 4, 6]
```

An example of capturing the result is given in the description for [`vm.runInThisContext()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options)

Comment: Thanks @jonathan. It worked. Is it possible to run this in a separate process. I mean how would you advice to handle case like "while (true) {}"

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal To run it as a separate process, you'll have to use the [`child_process` module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/child_process.html). If you can save the user's input to a file, then it can be run with [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options). To receive the result, you can require the script to `.send()` it – [how to send message to parent process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394206/how-to-send-message-to-parent-process)

Comment: How to use Node VM with source maps?